# Laravel Internal Error Page is showing exception message instead generic error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, internal-server-error

I have an laravel 5.7 application that when I deactivate debug mode the internal server error page keeps showing the exception message instead of the generic message "Whoops, something went wrong on our servers!".

[image]

Here is the code of Exception Handler:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryException;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that should not be reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
        \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
        \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
        \Illuminate\Database\QueryException::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }

    /**
     * Convert an authentication exception into an unauthenticated response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if ($request->expectsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthenticated.'], 401);
        }

        return redirect()->guest('login');
    }
}
```

I have no custom 500 error view and the Exception Handler is by default.
Do anyone knows why this is happening?

Best Regards

Comment: In `.env` file are you sure  `APP_DEBUG` is equal to `true`?

Comment: APP_DEBUG is false and I don´t want the degub mode active. I just don´t want to user to see the exception's messages in frontend.

Comment: Please give code of `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

Comment: Exceptions\Handler code added to question @SerhiiPosternak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

I ran a fresh install of composer and the exception message disappeared.

Thanks for all the answers given so far

Answer (score 2):

File .env

```
APP_DEBUG=false
```

File config/app.php

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', false),
```

Run command

```
php artisan config:cache
```

Comment: I have those configurations the way you suggested @Nick

Answer (score 1):

You can do in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` something like this:

```
if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {

        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 404) {
            return response()->view('partials.error' . '_404', [], 404);
        }

        if ($exception->getStatusCode() == 403) {
            return response()->view('partials.error' . '_403', [], 403);
        }
    }

    if ($exception instanceof QueryException) {
        abort(500);
    }
```

also, you could make the `instanceof ErrorException` to keep it more generic

Answer (score 1):

Well, we don't really have much to go on here. If I were to make a guess though, I will say it seems you're attempting to invoke a controller, AdsController, that you have not created yet.
Confirm in your app/Http/Controllers directory that you have a file bearing the name AdsController.php

---Edits---

What you want to do is keep the `APP_DEBUG` set to `false` in your `.env` file in production. But in your development or offline environment, you will want that option set to `true` so as to provide you with the trusty detailed error message you are accustomed to getting.

Comment: I know that my controller is not created, I forced it to gerenate a internal server error. The problem is that the page instead of showing the generic message shows the exception message